# How to make buddy list with wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I can't find anything for buddy list. I tree with ListCtrl but it did not. How to i can make buddy list like Pidgin? :[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide exactly such appearance you would need to write a custom control yourself. This is not exceedingly difficult but is, of course, more work than just using a pre-made one. So if you can settle on something similar but not *exactly* the same, you could find using [wxDataViewCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_data_view_ctrl.html) simpler. You would still have to define your own custom http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_data_view_ctrl.html for the middle column however.